# knockoutJS execute callback after foreach finishes rendering

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

In my code i want to execute function or callback just after KnockoutJS `foreach` binding finishes rendering all the items

i know i can do this simply by check if I'm at the last element (i found that here [execute code after the last item has been rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385679/knockout-execute-code-after-the-last-item-has-been-rendered)).
But using this my callback function 'll be called each time a new element or record is rendered.

I want to execute my callback function only once (for performance).

**UPDATE**

another solution is here [success callback after knockout.js finishes rendering all the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements?rq=1). but again using this my callback function 'll be called each time a new element is rendered.

Comment: Have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254317/success-callback-after-knockout-js-finishes-rendering-all-the-elements?rq=1?

Comment: it's the same, using **afterRender** 'll cause the callback function to be executed each item is rendered

Comment: If the check for being the last element is the first thing in the handler, it won't perform that badly.

Comment: @Tyrsius i agree with you.. but this mean i have no other option right?

Comment: None that I know of, but that doesn't mean none exists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that a good solution for this type of issue is to use a custom binding. It would be something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.doSomething = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //grab a dependency to the obs array

        //do something based on "element" (the container)
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items, doSomething: items">
     <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The `doSomething` needs to grab its own dependency to `items`, as `foreach` updates inside of its own computed observable and in KO 3.0 bindings will be independent.  You could also pass options to `doSomething` and then grab a dependency by accessing the observableArray through `allBindingsAccessor().foreach` (the third arg), if you always couple it with `foreach`.

Here is a sample that randomizes the background color of each element in the observableArray whenever once on each change to the observbaleArray: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SCqaS/

Comment: sorry i didn't get it completely, how is **doSomething** is depending on items, or what's the change that make it to be called ?

Comment: In KO, bindings are implemented inside of a computed observable. Any observables that have their value accessed create dependencies. In this case by calling `ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())` we are creating a dependency, if the value passed was an observable/observableArray.  So, whenever that observable is updated, this code will run again. Hope that helps.

Comment: very good..one more question how **foreach** is going to change items array? i think it's just read items values!

Comment: If you look at the sample fiddle, I am pushing new items to the observableArray, which triggers an update.  So, `foreach` and this custom binding both react to changes in the observableArray.  If you are binding against an array that does not change, then the binding can just run once the first time and it does not need to run again.