# Knockoutjs custom binding are executed before items are fully rendered

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

I'm trying to execute callback on list of items to make pagination using [DataTable](http://datatables.net/). Now i want to execute my callback after all my items have been rendered not after each item is rendered. Following that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552042/knockoutjs-execute-callback-after-foreach-finishes-rendering) i created simple custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ConvertToDataTable = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var list = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); //grab a dependency to the obs array        
        var tableId = allBindings().tableId;
        $('#' + tableId).dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
        });
    }
}
```

My view is:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-bind="attr: { id: tableId }">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Task Name</td>
            <td>Task Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: tasks, ConvertToDataTable: tasks, tableId: tableId -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Details"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That code works fine but with small number of items. but incase of big number of recoreds(e.g 500) the custom binding is executed before my items are fully renedered..Any Ideas?

**Update**
I get my data from server via AJAX, so maybe my custom binding is executed first while my observable array `items` is empty

Answer (score 3):

From a logical point of view, shouldn't the `ConvertToDataTable` binding be on the table itself, instead on the `foreach`?

Also, shouldn't you control table layout via the binding or the view model? The custom binding is a very bad place for hard-coded values.

Anyway, `controlsDescendantBindings` is your friend ([docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)):

Custom Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var layout = valueAccessor();

        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
        $(element).dataTable({ "sDom": layout });
    }
};
```

View Model:

```
{
    dataTableLayout: "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    tasks: ko.observableArray([/* ... */])
}
```

Template:

```
<table data-bind="dataTable: dataTableLayout">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Task Name</td>
            <td>Task Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tasks">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Details"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WcaM5/

**Disclaimer**: I don't know exactly how jQuery DataTables work, so the sample is aircode. The point I want to make is that you can take manual control over the binding if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for help, but i still get the same problem the custom binding is executed before my items has been rendered

Comment: `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` is a blocking call - it does not return before all descendant bindings are applied. See http://jsfiddle.net/WcaM5/1/, pay attention to the console. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: I'll second Mariusz comment. This is ABSOLUTELY the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom binding that I use! This covers any datatables options that you want to define in the binding...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
page: 0,
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  ko.unwrap(options.data);
  if(options.dataTableOptions.paging){
    valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
        var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
        table.destroy();
    }, null, 'arrayChange');         
  }
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
        if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node); 
        }
    });
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {       
    var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
    ko.unwrap(options.data);
    var table;
    if(!options.dataTableOptions.paging){
      table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    }
    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
    if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
       if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0)
           table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);               
       else
           table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);               
    }       
    if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
};
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/5pznw6re/)

Comment: Why are you unwrapping the options.data and not using the returned unwrapped value?

Also, I think that you don't want to unwrap the data since it might be an observableArray that you are going to subscribe.

P.S. Thanks for the contribution. I am now using this binding with some little changes my own.

Comment: That was a trick to get the binding to work correctly... ko.unwrap(options.data) sets dependecies... look here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html

Comment: @ricardobrandão If you have any changes please contribute to the github project.. :D  I welcome pull requests.  I want there to be a standard binding for this that everyone will be able to use. Thanks https://github.com/zachpainter77/DatatablesForEach-Custom-Knockout-Binding

Comment: Sorry but after reading the documentation I still don't understand what you are doing there. In my binding I just removed those lines.

Now I am trying to solve a problem with the DataTables' FixedColumns. Just created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34230052/3499186) for that.

Comment: @ricardobrandão Honestly I don't understand it fully myself.. But I know that my code does not work without it unless I modify the source of knockout to add events to the foreach binding. Here is a stackoverflow related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974917/reevaluating-a-knockout-computed-which-depends-just-on-an-observable-array

Comment: I don't like this about knockout myself.  Which is why I made a pull request with knockout --> here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1856

Comment: @ricardobrandão you will run into issues if you need to be able to add  or remove rows to the table in the user interface... like calling `someObservableArray.push(aNewRow);` The jQuery datatable will not reinitialize. if `ko.unwrap(options.data);` is removed.

Comment: I saw some code and read some comments about **triggering the knockout dependency tracker** which I can understand (although I was hoping that the tracking was always done in those cases). ---With your original binding, when you call the **destroy()** function when the array changes, you reset the table settings completely (e.g. UI, sorts). One thing that can help it using the **clear()** instead. However, you will still need to repopulate the datatable's data. P.S. In my original use case I just want to show some data and allow users to sort, filter, and select rows.

Comment: Trust me, I've tried that. ;) The only way knockout will work with datatables correctly is to completely destroy the datatable, let knockout render its originally bound template and last reinitialize the table. If you want to be able to add and remove records, that is... for simple viewing/sorting there are many other less complicated bindings out there. My binding allows a user to add/edit/delete/sort/filter (CRUD) operations on all data in a database. That was my intention for the binding.