# Reevaluating a Knockout computed which depends just on an observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

My Appmodel consists of an observable array of comments

```
self.comments=ko.observableArray([]);  // Default Value is an empty array
/*
   Here comes some code to initially fill the observable array 
   with items from an JSON Response
*/
```

Furthermore I have two computeds which should represent the very first comment and the last comment

```
self.firstComment = ko.computed(function () {
    var sorted = self.comments.sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
    return sorted[0];
});

self.lastComment = ko.computed(function () {
    var sorted = self.comments.sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
    return sorted[sorted.length - 1];
});
```

This works perfectly on initializing the application (loading the JSON from Server, build up App model...), but when I add a comment to the array, the computeds do not recognize that the number of array items has changed (as I understood it, an observable array is just an observable where the array properties themselves are observed). So when I do:

```
self.comments.push(aNewCommentObject);
```

self.lastComment is still bound to the array item, that it was when the app loaded initially.

I have found [this blog post](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/07/12/forcing-computed-observables-to-refresh-in-knockout/) how to force computation by introducing a dummy observable, but I don't like the approach. For what purpose is an observableArray used then and how?

**Additional Challenge:** I would like to keep the observableArray Items sorted under every circumstance (because its a comment feed which should be just sorted chronologically). I tried to do this whith an computed `commentsSorted` but also have problems that this does not update when the observableArray has new items, so same problem here. Thats the reason, why I am sorting everytime in firstComment and lastComment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try unwrapping the comments to trigger Knockout's dependency tracking:

```
self.firstComment = ko.computed(function () {
    var sorted = self.comments().sort(function (left, right) {
        // -------------------^^ !
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
    return sorted[0];
});
```

or (same thing):

```
self.firstComment = ko.computed(function () {
    var sorted = ko.unwrap(self.comments).sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
    return sorted[0];
});
```

Of course you can abstract this into a separate computed.

```
self.commentsSorted = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.comments().sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
});

self.firstComment = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.unwrap(self.commentsSorted)[0];
});
```

Since computeds cache their return values (just like every other observable does) you don't need to worry about calling `self.commentsSorted` multiple times. It will re-calculate only when the underlying observable array chances.

Comment: Oh myy, yes that was it. Working on a single project as a knockout first timer for about 2 months now, and I am really struggling 95% of the time if the object I am facing at the moment is an observable and need to be unwrapped or not. Code gets a lot more complicated because of this, but I hope Knockout and I get friends soon ;) Thanks a lot, I think next knockout issue is just around the corner

Comment: Just use `ko.unwrap` on everything. It will deal with observables and plain values alike, you don't need to worry which is which (and your code gets more flexible this way, too)

Comment: @Jürgen Also: There are these helper functions that come in handy when `ko.unwrap()` is not enough: `ko.isObservable()`, `ko.isSubscribable()`, `ko.isWriteableObservable()`.

Comment: @Jürgen For example, `function (left, right) { return ko.unwrap(left.Id) - ko.unwrap(right.Id); }` is a lot more flexible and robust because it can deal with mapped and unmapped versions of the target objects.

Comment: I've read about these ones, but didn't make much use of them until now. I guess its time to do so. I often use ko.toJS() mainly in Firebug console to debug my view model tree. Whats the main difference between ko.toJS() and ko.unwrap()? P.S. thanks for the tip with the sorting function, thats exactly what I meant with "more complicated", but ko.unwrap() really seems to solve that.

Comment: `unwrap()` will unwrap *one layer*. `toJS()` is recursive. In regular code you will find yourself using `unwrap()` more often - it's the idiomatic way to solve a specific problem (*"dealing with one value within the view model"*). `toJS()` is for a different problem (*"passing the entire view model to the outside world"*).

Comment: `sort` is a mutator method. It modifies the underlying array. When called like in the question, `self.comments.sort`, it modifies the array and notifies any subscribers and bindings. If called like in the answer `self.comments().sort`, it still modifies the array, but it doesn't notify subscribers or bindings. Here's a simple solution: `if (self.comments()) { self.comments.sort(...); }`. Now you get both, a dependency on the array and notification of changes.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, @Michael. Looks like I have to fix my answer.

Comment: @Michael: I think the major problem here was, that `self.comments.sort` returns an observable, and not my array. So the returned object cannot be accessed via an index only. By unwrapping it, I get back a sorted array and can get the first or last element via the corresponding index. In this example I did not need to get notified about the sorting, I wanted to get notified if a new element gets pushed (what in fact was already working, I only was not able to use the resulting object in the right manner, my fault ;) )

Comment: I've added an answer that fully describes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

How can you "keep the observableArray items sorted under every circumstance"? My advice is to not try to sort the original array (I'll describe the pitfalls in more detail below) but to use a computed observable that returns a new, sorted array:

```
self.commentsSorted = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.comments.slice(0).sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });
});
```

An important thing to understand about the JavaScript Array `sort()` method is that it **changes the original array**. Knockout's `observableArray` wraps many of the array functions so they can be used directly on the `observableArray` object. That's why you can use `myObservableArray.sort()` instead of having to do `myObservableArray().sort()`. But the two aren't equivalent because Knockout wraps array mutator methods differently, approximately like this:

```
sort: function (sortFunction) {
    this.valueWillMutate();
    var result = this.peek().sort(sortFunction);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    return result;
}
```

So what's wrong with automatically changing the original `observableArray`?

1. It's hard to grasp what's going on. It's easy to either not get a dependency on the array and thus never update past the initialization, or to not notify of the change and thus break other elements from getting the correct view of the array.
2. Even if you do set it up correctly, you've now created a circular dependency because you have something that's updated whenever the array changes, which then updates the array again. Although Knockout currently disables this for synchronous updates of a computed observable (but that might change in the future), it will result in unbounded recursion if using a manual subscription or a computed with the `throttle` option.

Comment: Thats an important thing to know about observableArrays and an excellent answer. I'll use slice() to copy the array in the computed, but I have more questions about this. As stated above I bulk load comments into my array during initialization (about 500 issues, each with approx. 5 to 10 comments). I use the push() function of the array to load them. Isn't every push() triggering recomputation of the `commentsSorted`? Isn't every slice() creating a completely new array then? Isn't this incredibly slow and memory inefficient? I think I should deactivate dependency tracking here temporarely?

Comment: When loading multiple items into an observable array, you can use `myObsArray.push.apply(myObsArray, items)`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, using `subscribe`:

```
self.comments = ko.observableArray([]);

self.comments.subscribe(function(comments) {
    var sorted = comments.sort(function (left, right) {
        return left.Id() - right.Id();
    });

    self.firstComment(sorted[0]);
    self.lastComment(sorted[sorted.length - 1]);

});
```

Comment: As I understood it, subscribe should just be used if nothing else is possible, that means if you are not able to use computeds or if you have special things in your UI, that you are not able to solve with bindings. I already had a circle dependency (subscribe function changed another observable which itself changed the one I subscribed again and so on). Horrible debugging scenario...