# Knockout binding for DataTables with FixedColumns extension not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js, datatables

I am using the knockout-binding [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098667/3499186) for DataTables. However, when using the FixedColumns extension (which clones the original datatable to a new one) I *lose* the binding between the new datatable and the existing **viewmodel/bindingContext**.

For instance, having a selection checkbox on a fixed column to select items from the table will not behave as expected.

The binding looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = { 
page: 0,
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) { 
    var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    if (binding.options.paging) {
        binding.data.subscribe(function(changes) {
            var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
            ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
            table.destroy();
        }, null, 'arrayChange');
    }

    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function(node) {
        if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    });

    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';

    var table;
    if (!binding.options.paging) {
        table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);

    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(binding.options);

    if (binding.options.paging) {
        if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page === 0) {
            table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
        } else {
            table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
        }
    }

    if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (binding.data || binding.length)) {
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
    }

    return {
        controlsDescendantBindings: true
    };
}
```

[(See the full working example)](http://codepen.io/ricardobrandao/details/MKaYgY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with a binding that reapplies the knockout context to the cloned table (i.e. the fixed columns table) after its creation:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import ko from 'knockout';
import 'datatables.net';
import 'datatables.net-fixedColumns';

const defaultOptions = {
    deferRender: true,
    paging: true
};

ko.bindingHandlers.datatables = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        const $element = $(element),
            binding = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            options = binding.options || {};

        $.extend(true, options, defaultOptions);

        if (binding.rowTemplateId && binding.data) {

            // bind the header first
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModel, $element.find('thead')[0]);

            setupTableBody($element, binding, bindingContext);

            if (ko.isObservable(binding.data)) {

                // destroy and build the table again when the data changes
                binding.data.subscribe(() => {
                    $element.DataTable().destroy();
                    $element.find('tbody').remove();

                    setupTableBody($element, binding, bindingContext);
                    initializeDataTable(element, options);
                }, null, 'arrayChange');
            }
        }

        initializeDataTable(element, options);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, () => {
            $(element).DataTable().destroy();
        });

        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
    }
};

function initializeDataTable(element, options) {
    const table = $(element).DataTable(options);

    if (options.fixedColumns) {

        // we need to apply the context to the cloned table for the first time
        setTimeout(() => {
            applyBindingsToClonedRows(element, options.fixedColumns);
        }, 0);

        // register handler to fix the cloned table column width
        // when the table is (re)drawn
        table.on('draw.dt', (event) => {
            $(event.target).DataTable().fixedColumns().relayout();
        });

        // register handler to fix the cloned table binding context
        // when the table is (re)drawn
        table.on('draw.dt.DTFC', (event) => {
            applyBindingsToClonedRows(event.target, options.fixedColumns);
        });
    }
}

function setupTableBody($element, binding, bindingContext) {

    // render each element of the body with the template
    let tbody = $element.find('tbody')[0];
    if (!tbody) {
        tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        $element.append(tbody);
    }
    ko.renderTemplateForEach(ko.unwrap(binding.rowTemplateId), binding.data, {}, tbody, bindingContext);
}

function applyBindingsToClonedRows(originalTable, fixedColumnsOptions) {
    const $table = $(originalTable);
    const rows = $table.find('tbody>tr');

    if (fixedColumnsOptions.leftColumns) {
        const clonedRows = $table.parent().parent().parent().find('.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper .DTFC_Cloned').find('tbody>tr');
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            ko.applyBindings(ko.contextFor(rows[i]), clonedRows[i]);
        }
    }

    if (fixedColumnsOptions.rightColumns) {
        const clonedRows = $table.parent().parent().parent().find('.DTFC_RightBodyWrapper .DTFC_Cloned').find('tbody>tr');
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            ko.applyBindings(ko.contextFor(rows[i]), clonedRows[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a [github repo](https://github.com/ricardobrandao/knockout-datatables) that also contains some examples since it might help someone else.

If you feel like this answers the question please up vote and I'll mark it as an answer -  it surely answers my initial question but I would appreciate some feedback.

**Please notice that this is ES2015 code so you'll need to transpile it.**

Answer (score 1):

Wow... That is a tough question. I'm thinking that you would either need to make the html available before the bindings are applied, or you would need to clone your data and apply the bindings to that.  The first option is out of the question since the fixedColumns plugin gets called when the datatable is initialized. which is happening inside this binding, and that happens when ko.applyBindings is called. Paradoxical.. :)

I also wanted to add that you are not losing your bindings because of fixed columns. The bindings are still there.  It's just that the new html that the plugin creates floats above the original binded html.

I did however get this hack to work...

Add this after applybindings is called...

Edit: Needed to bind the event to the document since fixed column plugin rewrites elements on the fly depending on the page.

```
$(document).on('click','.DTFC_LeftBodyWrapper input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
   var value = $(this).attr('value');
     $('.dataTables_scrollBody').find('input[value="'+value+'"]').click(); });
```

I figured if you cant bind the cloned html then you can force it to interact with the original html... It's really hacky but it works.. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[forked working example CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrvvWx)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too. I tried to applyBindingsToNode to the new **cloned** after its initialisation without success.---
---
Yes, I also noticed that I am not *loosing* the context (using ko.contextFor(...) on the new table shows that the bindingContext is there). However, somehow the 2-way binding for that table is *broken*.---
---
Yes, it is kinda hacky but it is a start :p Thanks for your input!

Comment: of course the binding is still there... all the fixed column plugin is doing is taking your specified columns, cloning them into a new table, and displaying that complete seperate table above your original table in a fixed position. If you right click the fixed columns and inspect in your debugger and find it's parent `<table>` tag, and change its display style to `display:none;` you will see that your original table is still there and still bound to your observable array.

Comment: As for this "However, somehow the 2-way binding for that table is broken" -- No, it is not "broken".  It simply did not exist when knockout started applying bindings to the html.  The **cloned** columns are created after knockout has applied the bindings.  Also, to consider this: Every time your user will select a new page the **cloned** columns will be deleted and replaced by new html. Knockout does not play very nice with dynamic html.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I was with a lot of work and then I went to holidays. I will try a revamp on this one more time this week. 

Yes, I understand that the binding does not exist. However, I was hoping that re-applying the binding to the DOM element (after the fixed columns initialization) would solve that.

Comment: No.. reapplying the bindings to the "fixed columns" will not solve that. I tried over and over to come up with a solution but kept running in circles. Your best bet, IMHO, to deal with fixed columns is to write your own event handler for interacting with the "fixed columns" that will programmatically interact with the original knockout bound datatable columns.

Comment: Hi Zach, 
I've created a new binding for the datatables.net where I reapply the bindings to the new (i.e. cloned) table and it works like a charm :). It also fixes some other problems like fixing the column size when moving to another page. I'll create a repo on github for that (it might help someone else) and add an answer to this question ASAP.