# Knockoutjs components callback after loaded all items in foreach

Tags: javascript, facebook, knockout.js

I have a component in knockoutjs for creating list of albums from Facebook using javascript graph api.

How can I call function after render all items?

I have tried `foreach: {data: items, afterRender: afterItemsLoaded}` - method `afterItemsLoaded` is called for every row not after render all items.

I have tried to use following code:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>List: </h1>
<list></list>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var countOfItemLoaded = 0;

ko.components.register('list', {
    viewModel: function() {
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="foreach: {data: items, afterRender: afterItemsLoaded}"><div data-bind="text: $data"></div></div>'
});

var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/410564482402231/albums?fields=photos,name,photos.name",  function (result) {   
            $.each(result.data,function(key, item)  {            
                self.items.push(item.name);
            });

    });


    self.afterItemsLoaded = function() {
        countOfItemLoaded = countOfItemLoaded + 1;
        alert("Loaded item " + countOfItemLoaded);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**Demo in jsFiddle:**

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gthqvr5n/2/)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? I added another variable but could not avoid the per component call back. I just used the length to manage when to execute the code needed. http://jsfiddle.net/sbjumani/gthqvr5n/3/

Comment: Is that even possible? think about it, each item that you add to the observable array, the array and even KO for that matter is unaware of how many items are going to be added. I would suggest calling a `loadComplete` method once all the items are added. This is just an example http://jsfiddle.net/gthqvr5n/5/

Comment: Both solutions work absolutely correctly. I'm looking for method or solution native in knockoutjs foreach which will be return this callback, Is there any method or I have to use this workaround something like above?

Comment: @Jenan Try the rateLimit option with notifyWhenChangesStop http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html. It will add an artificial delay but then again you want to find out when the observable has been completely populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think support has been added for this yet.

See: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/339

Ryan Niemeyer who works on Knockout did offer this solution to someone else almost 2 years ago
[knockoutJS execute callback after foreach finishes rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552042/knockoutjs-execute-callback-after-foreach-finishes-rendering)